# Click button without name & id

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to click button below;

```
<button class="gwt-Button leftButton" type="button">sign in</button>
```

I tried all possible ways to my knowledge with no success. 
Code below doesn't work at all

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
    If element.GetAttribute("class").Contains("leftButton") Then
        element.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next
```

I tried InnerText & InnerHtml, I get nullreferenceexception was unhandled at "Then"

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
    If element.InnerText.Contains("leftButton") Then
        element.InvokeMember("click")
    End If
Next
```

If I use the code below, I get "Found" message

```
Dim pagetext As String
Dim searchtext As String
searchtext = "Sign In"
pagetext = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.InnerText
If InStr(pagetext, searchtext) > 0 Then
    MsgBox("found")
```

So how can I convert MsgBox("found") piece to click button?

Comment: It works if I write the code to type="button" but there are multiple buttons on the page and all get clicked

Comment: try changing your <button  to be  <input, then your loop to look for input elements

Comment: You are calling all this code from the method associated with the DocumentCompleted event, don't you?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? It looks like you probably want to do something in javascript, not code-behind.

Comment: I figured it out. Outerhtml did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct code

```
For Each element As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("button")
If element.OuterHtml.Contains("leftButton") Then
    element.InvokeMember("click")
End If
Next
```